# how to detect middle or three quarters of scroll position on ListView on Flutter to lazy loading data?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

how to detect middle or three-quarters of scroll position on ListView? I want to get data after reach to middle or three-quarters of the scroll position. How to do it?

Currently, I get data on the end of listView.

```
_scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);

  void scrollListener(){
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      getMoreData();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can apply basic maths formula using the values maxScrollExtent and current scroll pixels . What's so hard? Try atleast

Comment: @OMiShah thanks. I thought my way is wrong.there is another way to do it. solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work..

```
_scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);

  void scrollListener(){
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.75) {
      getMoreData();
    }
  }
```

Comment: It should be working just fine, try it and set it as the correct answer if it does.

Comment: @user, kindly edit your answer so that I can undo my vote. It was a mistake.

Comment: @OMiShah i just did